# How log4net doesn't clear log each time calling XmlConfigurator.Configure() in a process

Tags: c#, .net, log4net

In my application, I include 3 libraries:

```
Log4net
Common.Logging.log4net
Quartz (use Common.Logging.log4net to write logs)
```

This is my log4net section config:

```
<log4net>
    <root>
        <level value="ALL" />
        <appender-ref ref="FileAppender" />
    </root>
    <appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
        <file value="quartz.log" />
        <appendToFile value="false" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
</log4net>
```

Everything is ok but having a problem about XmlConfigurator.Configure(). This command are called 2 times by order:

> - Called when init application -> I write log.
> - Called when starting Quartz. (I verified when to read source codes Common.Logging.log4net) -> Quartz write log.

After Quartz started, my logs was cleared because of XmlConfigurator.Configure(). This means that when calling this command, log will be cleared. I don't want my log is cleared after this command called **in a process**.

I can get source dll Common.Logging.log4net to change code to check whether log4net is really configured yet, and calling XmlConfigurator.Configure() if not. But I don't like this solution.

Please help me to find another solution without change codes in DLL library.

More info: http://neilkilbride.blogspot.com/2008/04/configure-log4net-only-once.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have configured that the file appender creates a  new log file when log4net is reconfigured:

```
 <appendToFile value="false" />
```

Change this to:

```
 <appendToFile value="true" />
```

The log messages will be appended at the end of file, even if you call `XmlConfigurator.Configure()` multiple times.

Comment: Your solution is ok but I want process will clear log when starting. So I must write more to archive my purpose. Anyways thank you.